# Am I in the right place for my purpose?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I am experienced with VB but I am taking a class in c++. I have written several c++ programs for my instructor but she states my code is inefficient. She rips apart my code stating I use too many strings. She isn't interested in sitting down in a civil way to show me why it is inefficient. So I am desperate. Would it be possible for me to paste one of my assignments here and the code I wrote for it so that some one could describe why it is so wrong and tell me what I should have written and why? Or am I in the wrong place for that? Please help. I am not looking for anything but true learning here. I'm not looking to have someone's input justify what I wrote so I can take it to my teacher and say "look someone on the internet thought it was good" or anything like that. All I want is to get it right.

Comment: I think that would be in order. There is also http://codereview.stackexchange.com precisely for that.

Comment: I think pasting in a *short* code snippet and asking why it is inefficient would be reasonable here.

Comment: This question should be migrated to meta

Comment: Don't ask to ask, just ask!

Comment: Pass your strings by `const std::string&` wherever possible.  Beyond that, your code is probably fine.

Answer (score 6):

If you want review of a complete program, please post it on the [code review stackexchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you have some *specific question* about a program or (preferably) a small part of a program, feel free to post it on stack overflow. Questions about what is appropriate on one site or another should be posted on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) (don't worry about this one, it'll probably be moved there soon).